# How to use the "Usage In Use Indicator"

Tags: usb, hid

I'm trying to RTFM the [HID Usage Tables
FOR
Universal Serial Bus (USB) v1.22](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_22.pdf) and the second paragraph of section 14 (Telephony Device Page) has this to say:

> Indicators on a phone are handled by wrapping them in LED: Usage In Use Indicator and LED: Usage Selected
> Indicator usages. For example, a message-indicator LED would be identified by a Telephony: Message usage declared as
> a Feature or Output in a LED: Usage In Use Indicator collection.

I think this means that there is some way to get the the Telephony state in an output report (the "message-indicator" in their example), but I have no idea from this description how to implement this in a HID report descriptor.  Can someone provide an example section of a HID report descriptor that make use of the usage in use indicator as described?

Answer (score 0):

Found example of the **Usage in Use Indicator** in Example A.10 (p. 144) of [an older version (v1.12) of the same document](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) (I would recapitulate the example here, but copying content from the original document is disallowed)

Furthermore, Table 11.6 (General Device Indicators, p.21) of the v1.12 document clarifies the definition of the **Usage In Use Indicator** and section 3.4.4 (Alternate Types, p. 66) describe the effect of the **Usage In Use Indicator**.